# Can't pass array through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, session

Trying to have data passed to a php script so the said data can be added to the session.
The debug console log returns are the following: 
  the `quant` array is correct and `typeof` is object,  the JSON.stringified `data`'s type is string , lastly `success` from the ajax success.
In the PHP script var_dump return is `NULL`

```
    $('#bigsubmit').click(function() {
    var quant = [];
    $('.input-number').each(function() {
        var tmp = {};
        tmp.id = this.id;
        tmp.qu = $(this).val();

        quant.push(tmp);
    });
    console.log(quant);
    var data = JSON.stringify(quant);
    console.log(typeof(data));
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,           
        data: {
            data: data
        },
        success: function() { 
            console.log("success");     
        }
    });
```

the php script (url var)

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = $_POST['data'];
var_dump($_SESSION['test']);

?>
```

Comment: Can you try `var_dump`ing `$_POST` to see all of its elements? Also try changing your variable names, there's a lot of them named `data`, (this probably won't fix it though).

Comment: _"In the PHP script var_dump return is `NULL`"_  I'm curious about this part. How exactly are you viewing this? If you're just opening the PHP URL in your browser, you will be overwriting `$_SESSION['test']` with an undefined value

Comment: yea i cant see the output on the site where the ajax is executed, i check it by opening the php script on a separate tab, so i wouldnt be able to access the post data there.

Answer (score 1):

Your `success callback function` isn't taking in a parameter, try changing to this,

```
success:function(data) {
   console.log(data);
}
```